# Filter products based on filter IDs

Tags: php

Good day,

I have an array (the request);

```
$appliedFilters = [
    "6",
    "37",
    "40",
    "41"
]
```

And then I have all products grouped by Filter Category (I know this is json output, but was easier to share);

```
{
   "6":[
      {
         "product_id":"12",
      }
   ],
   "7":[
      {
         "product_id":"12",
      }
   ],
   "12":[],
   "48":[
      {
         "product_id":"12",
      }
   ],
   "33":[],
   "34":[],
   "35":[],
   "36":[
      {
         "product_id":"12",
      }
   ],
   "37":[
      {
         "product_id":"12",
      }
   ],
   "38":[],
   "39":[],
   "40":[],
   "41":[]
}
```

How can I return all products where the $appliedFilters match the filters exactly the same?

I only need the product(s) where the $appliedFilters match the filterCategories exactly the same.

**For example**, the given `$appliedFilters` should return **0 products** because there are no products with a filter 40 or 41.

**Second example**

```
$appliedFilters = [
    "6",
    "36",
    "48"
]
```

In this case product with product_id = 12 should be returned because all the `$appliedFilters` has that product. It shouldn't matter if that product also has more filters like 7 and 48.

What I've tried so far is but the expected outcome is not correct:

```
// fetch all filter items
$productsGroupByFilterItems = [];
$rows = $this->getFilters();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $productsGroupByFilterItems[$row['filterItem_id']] = [];
}

// group all products by filter ids
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $productFilters = explode(',', $product['chosenFilterIds']);
    foreach ($productsGroupByFilterItems as $filterItemId => $filterItem) {
        foreach ($productFilters as $filterId) {
            if ($filterId == $filterItemId) {
                $productsGroupByFilterItems[$filterItemId][] = $product;
            }
        }
    }
}

// remove all products that are not part of the applied filters
foreach($productsGroupByFilterItems as $key => $val)
{
    if(array_search($key, $appliedFilters) === false)
    {
        unset($productsGroupByFilterItems[$key]);
    }
}

// finally return only the products that exist in all the filters items
return call_user_func_array('array_intersect_key', $productsGroupByFilterItems);
```

Comment: You should start by properly explaining your data model. And give examples that actually make sense. (The 48 from your second example does not seem to exist _at all_ in your filter data. So is that simply to be ignored then, or …?)

Comment: _“And then I have all products grouped by Filter Category”_ - which you created yourself, it is not your _original_ input data? In that case, maybe use a structure that is a bit more suitable for what you want to achieve here to begin with …?

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 0):

The code is too convoluted to parse through, but this may give you a start.

Assuming that the products are in `$products` as a PHP array, just flip `$appliedFilters` to create keys and then compute the intersection of the keys:

```
$result = array_intersect_key(array_flip($appliedFilters), $products);
```

This will give you all items in `$products` where the key is in `$appliedFilters`.  To do the opposite look at [array_diff_key](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php).

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this (I converted your JSON into simple array).

```
$filteredData = [
    6 => [
        ['product_id' => 12]
    ],
    7 => [
        ['product_id' => 12]
    ],
    12 => [],
    48 => [
        ['product_id' => 12]
    ],
    33 => [],
    34 => [],
    35 => [],
    36 => [
        ['product_id' => 12]
    ],
    37 => [
        ['product_id' => 12]
    ],
    38 => [],
    39 => [],
    40 => [],
    41 => []
];

//case 1
$appliedFilters = [
    "6",
    "37",
    "40",
    "41"
];

$out = array_intersect_key($filteredData, array_flip($appliedFilters));
$products = null;

foreach ($out as $filteredProducts) {
    if ($products === null) {
        $products = $filteredProducts;
        continue;
    }

    $products = @array_intersect($products, $filteredProducts);
}

var_dump($products);

//case 1
$appliedFilters = [
    "6",
    "36",
    "48"
];

$out = array_intersect_key($filteredData, array_flip($appliedFilters));
$products = null;

foreach ($out as $filteredProducts) {
    if ($products === null) {
        $products = $filteredProducts;
        continue;
    }

    $products = @array_intersect($products, $filteredProducts);
}

var_dump($products);
```

Results are:

```
//case 1
array(0) {
}

//case 2
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["product_id"]=>
    int(12)
  }
}
```

You can see it in action here: https://3v4l.org/JEjcB

Basically, we intersect the keys of filtered array and filter keys. And after that intersect all product arrays in a loop.